# How to find out if Python is compiled with UCS-2 or UCS-4?

Tags: python, unicode, ucs2

Just what the title says.

```
$ ./configure --help | grep -i ucs
  --enable-unicode[=ucs[24]]
```

Searching the official documentation, I found this:

> **[sys.maxunicode](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/sys.html#sys.maxunicode)**: An integer giving the
>   largest supported code point for a
>   Unicode character. The **value** of this
>   depends on the configuration option
>   that specifies whether Unicode
>   characters are stored as UCS-2 or
>   UCS-4.

What is not clear here is - which value(s) correspond to UCS-2 and UCS-4.

The code is expected to work on Python 2.6+.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

When built with --enable-unicode=ucs4:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.maxunicode
1114111
```

When built with --enable-unicode=ucs2:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.maxunicode
65535
```

Comment: This is not universally correct anymore for Python 3. See https://docs.python.org/3.4/c-api/unicode.html: `Since the implementation of PEP 393 in Python 3.3, Unicode objects internally use a variety of representations`. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: `deficient_unicode_build = (sys.maxunicode < 0x10ffff)` works on any Python version (even if the flexible internal representation is used where `sys.maxunicode == 0x10ffff`). The flexible representations allows to get correct results like ucs4 did on previous versions while using less memory than ucs4 in some cases.

Answer (score 20):

It's 0xFFFF (or 65535) for UCS-2, and 0x10FFFF (or 1114111) for UCS-4:

```
Py_UNICODE
PyUnicode_GetMax(void)
{
#ifdef Py_UNICODE_WIDE
    return 0x10FFFF;
#else
    /* This is actually an illegal character, so it should
       not be passed to unichr. */
    return 0xFFFF;
#endif
}
```

The maximum character in UCS-4 mode is defined by the maxmimum value representable in UTF-16.

Comment: Note that this function is _not_ used to implement `sys.maxunicode` after python 3.3 (ie, all maintained version of python as of this comment) - it only concerns the size of the now-deprecated `Py_UNICODE` typedef. `maxunicode` originates from `SET_SYS_FROM_STRING("maxunicode", PyLong_FromLong(0x10FFFF));`.

Answer (score 11):

I had this same issue once.  I documented it for myself on my wiki at

http://arcoleo.org/dsawiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Python%20UTF%20-%20UCS2%20or%20UCS4

I wrote -

```
import sys
sys.maxunicode > 65536 and 'UCS4' or 'UCS2'
```

Comment: For anyone wondering what this does: it is an old (< Python 2.5) way of doing `'UCS4' if sys.maxunicode > 65536 else 'UCS2'`.

Answer (score 10):

[sysconfig](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sysconfig.html) will tell the unicode size from the configuration variables of python.

The buildflags can be queried like this.

**Python 2.7:**

```
import sysconfig
sysconfig.get_config_var('Py_UNICODE_SIZE')
```

**Python 2.6:**

```
import distutils
distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('Py_UNICODE_SIZE')
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found a semi-official piece of code that does exactly that and may be interesting for people with the same issue: https://bitbucket.org/pypa/wheel/src/cf4e2d98ecb1f168c50a6de496959b4a10c6b122/wheel/pep425tags.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#pep425tags.py-83:89.

It comes from the wheel project which needs to check if the python is compiled with ucs-2 or ucs-4 because it will change the name of the binary file generated.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create an Unicode array and look at the itemsize:

```
import array
bytes_per_char = array.array('u').itemsize
```

Quote from the [`array` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html):

> The `'u'` typecode corresponds to Python’s unicode character. On narrow Unicode builds this is 2-bytes, on wide builds this is 4-bytes.

Note that the distinction between narrow and wide Unicode builds is dropped from Python 3.3 onward, see [PEP393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/). The `'u'` typecode for `array` is deprecated since 3.3 and scheduled for removal in Python 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

65535 is UCS-2:

> [Thus code point U+0000 is encoded as the number 0, and U+FFFF is encoded as 65535 (which is FFFF16 in hexadecimal).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2)