# Problem importing latest Pyside version

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I get:

ImportError: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/PySide/QtCore.so: undefined symbol: _ZN8Shiboken4Enum16createGlobalEnumEP7_objectPKcS4_S4_P11_typeobject

when I do

import PySide

After installing the new version of PySide, version 1.0.6 isolino

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 1):

This could be an old shiboken running with a new PySide version. Could you confirm that you're using the latest version (shiboken 1.0.6)? If you're using Ubuntu, the python-pyside package should ensure that all the modules are properly updated - see http://bugs.pyside.org/show_bug.cgi?id=999

Comment: Yes this was indeed the case, the libshiboken was the wrong version. I went to the repository got the file then replaced my copy. Every thing then worked honky dory.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when I was building python libraries against a python version that was using a different unicode encoding ("ucs4" vs "ucs2").

I would make sure that your python interpreter is built the same was as the pyside modules.

[How to find out if Python is compiled with UCS-2 or UCS-4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446347/how-to-find-out-if-python-is-compiled-with-ucs-2-or-ucs-4)