# Virtualenv and Python ucs-4

Tags: python, virtual

How can I convert an existing virtualenv python to become compatible with UCS4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not make much sense to me as it does lacks a lot of information.

Based on my Unicode experience, I would believe that you are using Python on Windows, probably a Python 2.

UCS-4 is just one Unicode encoding, which happens not to be the one used internally by Python.

Here is something that would help you debug the issue [How to find out if Python is compiled with UCS-2 or UCS-4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446347/how-to-find-out-if-python-is-compiled-with-ucs-2-or-ucs-4)

And regarding modules, you need to reinstall all the binary ones, the pure python ones would not need any change.