# undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_AsLatin1String

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I have installed python2.7 and while executing my application getting error as like

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so: undefined
>   symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_AsLatin1String

Also i checked by build and displays as 'UCS2'

How can we resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Just recompile your python with option `./configure --enable-unicode=ucs2`, It will be get fixed.

Comment: Actually the solution for me was to build with `--enable-unicode=ucs4`. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446347/how-to-find-out-if-python-is-compiled-with-ucs-2-or-ucs-4