# What is the numpy pypi package naming convention

Tags: numpy, pypi

Trying to determine which numpy package is compatible with my python environment.  My server has no internet access, so I need to download and install the package locally.

I know the cp27 refers to Python 2.7, but what is the difference between these two packages:

```
numpy-1.12.0rc1-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
numpy-1.12.0rc1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differing part is an [ABI tag](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/#abi-tag).

- `mu` indicates `--enable-unicode=ucs4`
- `m` on its own is `--enable-unicode=ucs2`

See [UCS-2 vs UCS-4 builds](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/#ucs-2-vs-ucs-4-builds); to determine which you need for your current installation, see [How to find out if Python is compiled with UCS-2 or UCS-4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1446347/3001761)

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know how you found this.