# Python unicode - UCS2 vs UCS4

Tags: python-2.7, ucs2, ucs-4

I came across a scenario where I have to choose between UCS-2 and UCS-4. 
What is the significance of UCS-2 vs UCS-4 related to Python? How are they different?

Comment: You type this verbatim into google for several answers, many on SO.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python. It's a question about the differences between UCS2 and UCS4, which can be found with a simple Google search. All Python does is use them, just like any other language.

Comment: @KenWhite it comes up in python2.x since the internal representation can limit what a particularly compiled interpreter can represent. But also high on google hits.

Answer (score 0):

As for Python, UCS-2 and UCS-4 define largest supported code point for a Unicode characters. See some python related details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1446347/547270). In briefs, when Python is configured and built with UCS-4 it can support larger set of Unicode characters.