# building boost against custom python

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I am trying to compile boost against my custom build of python and getting "undefined reference" errors. Here go details:

1) I build python with support unicode=ucs4 as required by autodesk maya

```
./configure --prefix=/v/pkgs/python/dep/2.7.14 --enable-unicode=ucs4
make
make install
```

2) Build boost with this command

```
b2 -j 4 --layout=versioned --build-type=complete --debug-configuration stage
```

and config file ./tools/build/src/user-config.jam to use my build of python.

```
using python
    : 2.7
    : /v/pkgs/python/dep/2.7.14
    ;
```

This is part of b2 output, to confirm python selection success:

```
notice: [python-cfg] Configuring python...
notice: [python-cfg]   user-specified version: "2.7"
notice: [python-cfg]   user-specified cmd-or-prefix: "/v/pkgs/python/dep/2.7.14"
notice: [python-cfg] Checking interpreter command "/v/pkgs/python/dep/2.7.14/bin/python2.7"...
notice: [python-cfg] running command '/v/pkgs/python/dep/2.7.14/bin/python2.7 -c "from sys import *; print('version=%d.%d\nplatform=%s\nprefix=%s\nexec_prefix=%s\nexecutable=%s' % (version_info[0],version_info[1],platform,prefix,exec_prefix,executable))" 2>&1'
notice: [python-cfg] ...requested configuration matched!
notice: [python-cfg] Details of this Python configuration:
notice: [python-cfg]   interpreter command: "/v/pkgs/python/dep/2.7.14/bin/python2.7"
notice: [python-cfg]   include path: "/v/pkgs/python/dep/2.7.14/include/python2.7"
notice: [python-cfg]   library path: "/v/pkgs/python/dep/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/config" "/v/pkgs/python/dep/2.7.14/lib"
```

3) To verify I try to build following test.cpp

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
int main ()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    boost::python::object obj;
    return 0;
}
```

with this command (new lines for easier reading):

```
g++ -g -O2 
-I/v/pkgs/python/dep/2.7.14/include/python2.7 
-I/v/pkgs/boost/dep/1_61_0 
-L/v/pkgs/boost/dep/1_61_0/stage/lib 
-lboost_python-gcc48-mt-1_61
-L/v/pkgs/python/dep/2.7.14/lib 
-lpython2.7 
./test.cpp
```

I am getting following errors:

```
/v/pkgs/boost/dep/1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_python-gcc48-mt-1_61.so: undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS4_FromEncodedObject'
/v/pkgs/boost/dep/1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_python-gcc48-mt-1_61.so: undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS4_AsWideChar'
```

Any tips are welcome, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the python was not build with `UCS-4`, it was built with `UCS-2`.
In order to check this, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1446456/889576) on the much similar question.