# Python 2.7: Strange Unicode behavior

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, surrogate-pairs

I am experiencing the following behavior in Python 2.7:

```
>>> a1 = u'\U0001f04f'  #1
>>> a2 = u'\ud83c\udc4f'  #2
>>> a1 == a2  #3
False
>>> a1.encode('utf8') == a2.encode('utf8')  #4
True
>>> a1.encode('utf8').decode('utf8') == a2.encode('utf8').decode('utf8')  #5
True
>>> u'\ud83c\udc4f'.encode('utf8') #6
'\xf0\x9f\x81\x8f'
>>> u'\ud83c'.encode('utf8')  #7
'\xed\xa0\xbc'
>>> u'\udc4f'.encode('utf8')  #8
'\xed\xb1\x8f'
>>> '\xd8\x3c\xdc\x4f'.decode('utf_16_be')  #9
u'\U0001f04f'
```

What is the explanation for this behavior? More specifically:

1. I'd expect two strings to be equal if statement #5 is true, while #3 proves otherwise.
2. Encoding both code points together like in statement #6 yields results different from when encoded one by one in #7 and #8. Looks like the two code points are treated as one 4-byte code point. But what if I actually want them to be treated as two different code points?
3. As you can see from #9 the numbers in `a2` are actually `a1` encoded using UTF-16-BE but although they were specified as Unicode code points using `\u` inside a Unicode string (!), Python still could somehow get to equality in #5. How could it be possible?

Nothing makes sense here! What's going on?

Comment: You created UTF-16 surrogate pairs, those *represent* the same codepoint, so encoding puts them together.

Comment: Upgrade to Python 3 and you'll get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: surrogates not allowed`.

Comment: Also, you have a Python 2 UCS4 build. On a UCS2 build, #3 is *`True`*!

Comment: Wasn't aware of the concept of "surrogate pairs". How does Python know it is a surrogate pair and not two distinct code points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Python 2 is violating the Unicode standard here, by permitting you to encode codepoints in the range U+D800 to U+DFFF, at least in a UCS4 build. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+D800_to_U+DFFF):

> The Unicode standard permanently reserves these code point values for UTF-16 encoding of the high and low surrogates, and they will never be assigned a character, so there should be no reason to encode them. The official Unicode standard says that no UTF forms, including UTF-16, can encode these code points.

The official UTF-8 standard **has no encoding** for UTF-16 surrogate pair codepoints, so Python 3 raises an exception when you try:

```
>>> '\ud83c\udc4f'.encode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: surrogates not allowed
```

But Python 2's Unicode support is a bit more rudimentary, and the behaviour you observe varies with the [specific UCS2 / UCS4 build variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446347/how-to-find-out-if-python-is-compiled-with-ucs-2-or-ucs-4); on a UCS2 build, your variables are *equal*:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxunicode
65535
>>> a1 = u'\U0001f04f'
>>> a2 = u'\ud83c\udc4f'
>>> a1 == a2
True
```

because in such a build all non-BMP codepoints are encoded as UTF-16 surrogate pairs (extending on the UCS2 standard).

So on a UCS2 build there is no difference between your two values, and the choice to encode to the full non-BMP codepoint is *entirely valid* when you assume you would want to encode U+1F04F and other such codepoints. The UCS4 build just matches that behaviour.