# Python unicode indexing shows different character

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, ucs2, surrogate-pairs

I have a Unicode string in a "narrow" build of Python 2.7.10 containing a Unicode character. I'm trying to use that Unicode character as a lookup in a dictionary, but when I index the string to get the last Unicode character, it returns a different string:

```
>>> s = u'Python is fun \U0001f44d'
>>> s[-1]
u'\udc4d'
```

Why is this happening, and how do I retrieve `'\U0001f44d'` from the string?

Edit: `unicodedata.unidata_version` is 5.2.0 and `sys.maxunicode` is 65535.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: If that's a real MCVE, you have a very strange Python 2.7 build. Please edit into your question the values of `unicodedata.unidata_version` and `sys.maxunicode`?

Comment: @wim Added those edits. It is, in fact, a real MCVE.

Comment: Can't repro; https://ideone.com/y7jalr

Comment: I take it `len(u'\U0001f44d')` returns `2` on your Python?

Comment: @wim Yes, `len(u'\U0001f44d')` returns 2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404144/correctly-extract-emojis-from-a-unicode-string

Comment: I *can* in fact repro on MacOS Mojave using the preinstalled `/usr/bin/python`,  Perhaps your question should mention your platform (though it's visible from the screenshot if you know where to look).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Python 2 "narrow" build uses UTF-16 to store Unicode strings (a so-called [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction), so code points >U+FFFF are two UTF surrogates.  To retrieve the code point, you have to get both the leading and trailing surrogate:

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = u'Python is fun \U0001f44d'
>>> s[-1]     # Just the trailing surrogate
u'\udc4d'
>>> s[-2:]    # leading and trailing
u'\U0001f44d'
```

Switch to Python 3.3+ where the problem has been solved and storage details of Unicode code points in a Unicode string are not exposed:

```
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = u'Python is fun \U0001f44d'
>>> s[-1]   # code points are stored in Unicode strings.
'\U0001f44d'
```

Comment: The narrow build uses UCS-2, which is a little different to UTF-16. See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16 for details.

Comment: @PM2Ring "UCS-2 disallows use of [surrogates], but UTF-16 allows their use in pairs".

Comment: @JoshLee It's complicated. ;) Despite the support of surrogate pairs, the [Python 2.7 docs](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/sys.html#sys.maxunicode) refer to UCS-2. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/53140775/4014959

Comment: Java and JavaScript have very similar behavior but claim UTF-16 and not UCS-2 

Comment: The docs can say anything, but the behavior is UTF16. Microsoft calls UTF-16 “Unicode”. 

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your Python 2 build uses surrogates for representing code points outside of the Basic Multilingual Plane. See e.g. [How to work with surrogate pairs in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147259/how-to-work-with-surrogate-pairs-in-python) for a bit of background.

My recommendation would be to switch to Python 3 for anything involving string handling as soon as possible.